# Usages des mots « tacite » et « discret », quelle Différence ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Je voudrais connaitre la différence entre `tacite` et `discret`, et quand les utiliser ?

Comment: Dans quel contexte pourrait-il y avoir une confusion ? Le sens de ces mots est assez différent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tacite` signifie simplement **sous-entendu, non-exprimé explicitement**.

Dans le langage courant on l'utilise presque exclusivement avec : *un accord tacite*, *une règle tacite*, ou *un aveu tacite*.

A part ça, c'est surtout un terme de droit :

- un contrat à *recondution tacite* (à reconduction automatique)
- une garantie *expresse ou tacite*

En bref sauf si tu étudies la littérature, tu as peu de chances de tomber sur des phrases comme

> Le frémissement de son temple tacite (Paul Valéry, 1922)

---

A contrario, on utilise le mot `discret` dans des contextes très divers:

- sans bruit (ex: *J'entrais discrètement dans la pièce*)
- réservé (ex: *C'est quelqu'un d'assez discret, il ne parle pas beaucoup*)
- modéré/subtil (ex: *Cet arôme possède une discrète touche de vanille*)

Cf quelques exemples :
https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=french&query=discret

Ses synonymes: http://www.synonymes.com/synonyme.php?mot=discret&x=0&y=0

Enfin, en mathématiques ou en physique, on utilise `discret` par opposition à `continu`: il a donc ici le sens particulier de **dénombrable**.

- une somme *discrète* / une somme *finie* = une somme
- une somme infinie = une intégrale

Answer (score 1):

Une simple recherche dans un dictionnaire donne :

- [tacite](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tacite)
- [discret](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/discret)